# Can I make one monitor act like two, split in half

Tags: multiple-monitors, monitor, screen, split

Context: Ubuntu 11.10, Unity

Let's say I have a screen at resolution 1000x500.

#### What I'd like to do is split the screen down the middle so [Unity or X or ?] acts as if there are two displays (each of 500x500).

#### Examples:

- Unity will display a different toolbar (the top one) on each side of the display.
- If I maximize a window on the left side of the screen, it will fill the left side only.
- If I maximize on the right, it will fill the right.
- If I hit "fullscreen" in youtube (flash) or Chrome or Movie Player, it will only fill the side of the display that it's on.

#### If it's really is impossible to do this with Unity, will it work with Gnome3 and how?

## A million thanks!

Comment: PS: No, Compiz Grid is not enough. :)

Comment: If you go fullscreen with Flash and then click in a window on the other monitor, Flash leaves fullscreen :-(

Comment: A tiled window manager such as xmonad or its derivative Bluetile won't fulfill all the listed requirements, but may fit your use case well.

Answer (score 1):

Well for getting an application to fill half the screen just drag the title bar into the side of the window and it will expand to half the screen.

The rest I don't believe is possible in Unity, this suggests it might work with another window management system http://www.justlinux.com/forum/showthread.php?t=144351